# awk calculate euclidean distance results in wrong output

Tags: arrays, linux, for-loop, awk, settings

I have this small geo location dataset.

```
37.9636140,23.7261360
37.9440840,23.7001760
37.9637190,23.7258230
37.9901450,23.7298770
```

From a random location.
For example this one `37.97570, 23.66721`
I need to create a bash command with awk that returns the distances with simple euclidean distance.
This is the command i use

```
awk -v OFMT=%.17g -F',' -v long=37.97570 -v lat=23.66721 '{for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) distances[i]=sqrt(($1 - long)^2 + ($2 - lat)^2 ); a[i]=$1; b[i]=$2} END {for (i in distances) print distances[i], a[i], b[i]}' filename
```

When I run this command i get this weird result which is not correct, could someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

```
➜ awk -v OFMT=%.17g -F',' -v long=37.97570 -v lat=23.66721 '{for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) distances[i]=sqrt(($1 - long)^2 + ($2 - lat)^2 ); a[i]=$1; b[i]=$2} END {for (i in distances) print distances[i], a[i], b[i]}' filename                     

44,746962127881936 37.9440840 23.7001760
44,746962127881936 37.9901450 23.7298770
44,746962127881936 37.9636140 23.7261360
44,746962127881936  
44,746962127881936 37.9637190 23.7258230
```

Updated.

Appended the command that @jas provided, I included `od -c` as @mark-fuso suggetsted.

> The issue now is that I get different results from @jas

Command output which showcases the new issue.

```
awk -v OFMT=%.17g -F, -v long=37.97570 -v lat=23.66721 '
{distance=sqrt(($1 - long)^2 + ($2 - lat)^2 ); print distance, $1, $2}
' file        
1,1820150904705098 37.9636140 23.7261360
1,1820150904705098 37.9440840 23.7001760
1,1820150904705098 37.9637190 23.7258230
1,1820150904705098 37.9901450 23.7298770
```

> `od -c` that shows the content of the input file.

```
od -c file
0000000   3   7   .   9   6   3   6   1   4   0   ,   2   3   .   7   2
0000020   6   1   3   6   0  \n   3   7   .   9   4   4   0   8   4   0
0000040   ,   2   3   .   7   0   0   1   7   6   0  \n   3   7   .   9
0000060   6   3   7   1   9   0   ,   2   3   .   7   2   5   8   2   3
0000100   0  \n   3   7   .   9   9   0   1   4   5   0   ,   2   3   .
0000120   7   2   9   8   7   7   0  \n
0000130
```

Comment: Replace the `for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)` with `i=NR;`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin the issue is the same as I have responded to the answer's comment section.

Comment: I got the same output as that of in the answer. I cannot reproduce the output you got.

Comment: Could there be an issue with the locale setting? I see you get a comma instead of a decimal point when you print the distance.

Comment: Hello @jas thank you yes that was it. I had greek settings. Could you please append this to your answer and I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: I was actually looking for the details on the **input** file (not the output of the `awk` command); per your latest update you're calling the input file `file`, so `od -c file`; if you've determined the issue ties back to a locale setting, and jas' code is now working ... you can skip the whole `od -c ...` approach if you wish

Comment: Hello @markp-fuso no i think it is a good idea to leave it as is. If you feel I approached it wrong, feel free to edit. But yes the problem is with the locale

Comment: the only edit I would recommend is to run `od -c` against the **input** file ... don't need `od -c` run against the output from `awk` as the whole point was to see what's being fed to `awk`; and since I don't have access to your specific input file ... you'll need to do the edit ... your call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk takes care of the looping for you. The code will be run in turn for each line of the input file:

```
$ awk -v OFMT=%.17g -F, -v long=37.97570 -v lat=23.66721 '
{distance=sqrt(($1 - long)^2 + ($2 - lat)^2 ); print distance, $1, $2}
' file
0.060152679674309095 37.9636140 23.7261360
0.045676346307474212 37.9440840 23.7001760
0.059824979147508742 37.9637190 23.7258230
0.064310270672728084 37.9901450 23.7298770
```

**EDIT**:
OP is getting different results. I notice in OP's output that there are commas instead of decimal points when printing the `distance`. This points to a possible issue with the locale setting.

OP confirms that the locale was set for greek, causing the difference in output.

Comment: This does not yield the same result for me.
`➜ awk -v OFMT=%.17g -F, -v long=37.97570 -v lat=23.66721 '
{distance=sqrt(($1 - long)^2 + ($2 - lat)^2 ); print distance, $1, $2}
' filename
1,1820150904705098 37.9636140 23.7261360
1,1820150904705098 37.9440840 23.7001760
1,1820150904705098 37.9637190 23.7258230
1,1820150904705098 37.9901450 23.7298770
`

Comment: @panoskarajohn I get the same output as jas so I'm wondering what **exactly** is in  your data file; if you're still having issues I'd suggest updating the question to include the complete output from `od -c filename`;

Comment: @markp-fuso I updated my question so you can see `od -c` output

Comment: This seems to be a settings issue, I had greek settings on my ubuntu machine from my side. Once this is appended to the answer as extra information I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Good news! Updated.

Answer (score 6):

While @jas has provided a 'fix' for the problem, thought I'd throw in a few comments about what OP's code is doing ...

Some basics ...

- the `awk` program (`{for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) ... ; b[i]=$2}`) is applied against each row of the input file
- as each row is read from the input file the `awk` variable `NR` keeps track of the row number (ie, `NR=1` for the first row, `NR=2` for the second row, etc)
- on the last pass through the `for` loop the counter (`i` in this case) will have a value of `NR+1` (ie, the `i++` is applied on the last pass through the loop thus leaving `i=NR+1`)
- unless there are conditional checks for each line of input the `awk` program will apply against every line from the input file (including blank lines - more on this below)
- `for (i in distances)...` isn't guaranteed to process the array indices in numerical order

The `awk/for` loop is doing the following:

- for the 1st input row (`NR=1`) we get `for (i=1;i<=1;i++) ...`
- for the 2nd input row (`NR=2`) we get `for (i=1;i<=2;i++) ...`
- for the 3rd input row (`NR=3`) we get `for (i=1;i<=3;i++) ...`
- for the 4th input row (`NR=4`) we get `for (i=1;i<=4;i++) ...`

For each row processed by `awk` the program will overwrite all previous entries in the `distance[]` array; net result is the last row (`NR=4`) will place the same values in all 4 entries of the the `distance[]` array.

The `a[i]=$1; b[i]=$2` array assignments occur outside the scope of the `for` loop so these will be assigned once per input row (ie, will not be overwritten) however, the array assignments are being made with `i=NR+1`; net result is the contents of the 1st row (`NR=1`) are stored in array entries `a[2]` and `b[2]`, the contents of the 2nd row (`NR=2`) are stored in array entries `a[3]` and `a[3]`, etc.

Modifying OP's code with `print i, distances[i], a[i], b[i]}` and running against the 4-line input file I get:

```
1 0.064310270672728084                            # no data for 2nd/3rd columns because a[1] and b[1] are never set
2 0.064310270672728084 37.9636140 23.7261360      # 2nd/3rd columns are from 1st row of input
3 0.064310270672728084 37.9440840 23.7001760      # 2nd/3rd columns are from 2nd row of input
4 0.064310270672728084 37.9637190 23.7258230      # 2nd/3rd columns are from 3rd row of input
```

From this we can see the first column of output is the same (ie, `distance[1]=distance[2]=distance[3]=distance[4]`), while the 2nd and 3rd columns are the same as the input columns **except** they are shifted 'down' by one row.

That leaves us with two outstanding issues ...

- why does OP show 5 lines of output?
- why is the first column consist of the garbage `44,746962127881936`?

I was able to reproduce this issue by adding a blank line on the end of my input file:

```
$ cat geo.dat
37.9636140,23.7261360
37.9440840,23.7001760
37.9637190,23.7258230
37.9901450,23.7298770
                           <<=== blank line !!
```

Which generates the following with OP's `awk` code:

```
44.746962127881936
44.746962127881936 37.9636140 23.7261360
44.746962127881936 37.9440840 23.7001760
44.746962127881936 37.9637190 23.7258230
44.746962127881936 37.9901450 23.7298770
```

**NOTES**:

- this order is different from OP's sample output and is likely due to OP's `awk` version not processing `for (i in distances)...` in numerical order; OP can try something like `for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)...` or `for (i=1;i in distances; i++)...` (though the latter will not work correcly for a sparsely populated array)
- OPs output (in the question; in comment to @jas' answer) shows a comma (`,`) in place of the period (`.`) for the first column so I'm guessing OP's env is using a locale that switches the comma/period as thousands/decimal delimiter (though the input data is based on an 'opposite' locale)

Notice we finally get to see the data from the 4th line of input (shifted 'down' and displayed on line 5) but the first column has what appears to be a nonsensical value ... which can be tracked back to applying the following against a blank line:

```
sqrt(($1 - long)^2     + ($2 - lat)^2     )
sqrt((   - long)^2     + (   - lat)^2     )  # empty line => $1 = $2 = undefined/empty
sqrt((   - 37.97570)^2 + (   - 23.66721^2 )  
sqrt( 1442.153790      +    560.136829    )
sqrt( 2002.290619                         )
44.746952...                                 # contents of 1st column
```

To 'fix' this issue the OP can either **a)** remove the blank line from the input file or **b)** add some logic to the `awk` script to only perform calculations if the input line has (numeric) values in fields #1 & #2 (ie, `$1` and `$2` are not empty); it's up to the coder to decide on how much validation to apply (eg, are the fields numeric, are the fields within the bounds of legitimate long/lat values, etc).

---

One last design-related comment ... as demonstrated in jas' answer there is no need for any of the arrays (which in turn reduces memory usage) when all desired output can generated 'on-the-fly' while processing each line of the input file.